# Vitali convergence thm, weaken the uniform integrability

Tags: integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I have $f_n:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}^n$ which converge pointwise a.e.and are bounded.[ $[0,1]$ is also a possible domain]
Is it possible to weaken the condition of uniform integrability in the Vitali convergence theorem in the following way: instead of
 "...for all $E\subset(0,1),|E|<\delta$ there holds $|\int_Ef_ndx|\leq \epsilon$"
it is just needed
"... for all $0<r<\delta,x\in(0,1),B_r(x)\subset(0,1)$ there holds $|\int_{B_r(x)}f_ndx|\leq \epsilon$"
?
If not, is it possible to weaken the condition in this way if I got more information?